# Put a link to a category round a hard coded A HREF

Tags: php, categories, permalinks, slug

In my footer I have hard coded the links and would like to link some to there category, I could just copy the full URL to it and paste in the href="" but I would rather call it using php.

My knowledge of WordPress and PHP is little and I have tried searching for something that will do this but none work, my last go used this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'cooking-sauces' ) ); ?>">Cooking Sauces</a>
```

and I tried this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'cooking-sauces')->ID); ?>">Cooking Sauces</a>
```

but did not work.

So the full URL would be http://woloped.co.uk/blog/products/cooking-sauces/

Please can some one help, many thanks Dave

UPDATE: Could it be called using the SLUG and if yes have is this done please.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "page" in WordPress usually refers to a "PAGE page", as in only post of `page` post type. Not any *page* of the site in general.

What you want to link to is *category archive*. Something along this should work:

```
echo get_category_link( 'cooking-sauces' );
```

If `cooking-sauces` is slug of a *term* that belongs to custom *taxonomy* (as opposed to native *category* taxonomy) you will probably need to use something like:

```
echo get_term_link( 'cooking-sauces', 'your-taxonomy-slug' );
```

Comment: Hi @Rarst

Thanks for your reply and it kind of worked as I have one category that was create in the admin under Posts > Categories, however the categories I want to link to are part of the products section that is built into the theme so there is a tab for products and there you add the product categories so Cooking Sauces link is http://woloped.co.uk/blog/products/cooking-sauces/ I did try echo get_category_link( get_category_by_slug( 'products/cooking-sauces' ) ); but did not work.

Comment: yes it worked and a great big thankyou

Comment: @Dave you are welcome :) if this answers your question please mark it as accepted answer (green check mark) so that system recognizes thread as resolved

Comment: i can't find a green check box anywhere to mark this a resolved ???

Comment: @Dave well, grey originally :) to the left of the answer, under voting score and arrows